# Converting Dataframe into an Univariate Timeseries in R?

Tags: r, time-series, datetime-format, xts

I want to convert this dataframe into a univariate timeseries in R. To do so, I think I want to make the `date_time` column into an index? Let me know if this sounds correct. Here is a small subset of the actual dataframe:

```
date_time              price
2017-05-01 00:00:00    3040         
2017-05-01 01:00:00    3030         
2017-05-01 02:00:00    3068         
2017-05-01 03:00:00    3010         
2017-05-01 04:00:00    2814
```

Here is what I have tried to achieve this.

```
xts(df$price, as.Date(df$date_time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

However, this completely cuts off the hours, minute, and seconds. Therefore it outputs this:

```
              price
2017-05-01    3040         
2017-05-01    3030         
2017-05-01    3068         
2017-05-01    3010         
2017-05-01    2814
```

How can I include date as well as time in the index?

Comment: can you please dput() your data

Comment: as @amrrs noted, it is a problem of data type, the one you require need to handle both date and time. The library `chron` is another option.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `ss` is the dataframe name, the below code should work:

```
library(xts)

time <- as.POSIXct(ss$date_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#library(xts)

xt <- xts(x = ss$price, order.by = time)

xt1 <- xts(ss$price, strptime(ss$date_time, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

xt1

> xt1
                    [,1]
2017-05-01 00:00:00 3040
2017-05-01 01:00:00 3030
2017-05-01 02:00:00 3068
2017-05-01 03:00:00 3010
2017-05-01 04:00:00 2814
```

`as.Date()` will lose the `time` element hence it has to be typecasted to a `POSIXct` object.